# Is there somewhre in LinkedIn API to get who viewed my profile?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I want to display this info from the app im developing as part of frequently updated data from linkedIn. I've read the linkedin docs and done my research but couldn't find any hints that I might use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, this is not possible: http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/search-appearances-and-profile-views

Comment: Thanks! Would you know if there is a discussion of making this available via api soon?

Comment: Linkedin doesn't have a future roadmap, and they prefer not to comment on release dates, they just release features. See an example of such a reply here: http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2253

Answer (score 1):

If I ventured to guess, this is one of the selling points for people upgrading to premium memberships. So if they exposed getting the freemium version of this data (last 5 people), you could easily write an app to poll and get all, thus eliminating one of the biggest reasons to give them $30/month.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you could automate opening LinkedIn website and scrap the page to get the view information and log it somewhere, you could collate the list over time to capture the records.

I'm sure they would do anything to identify bot activities and block them, but you can probably do it.

Same could work for apps. I guess App would be easier to crack as not much protection would be present in Apps.